# Run gcc-4.8 on 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04, as: unrecognized option '--32'

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gcc4.8

I just installed 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 and gcc/g++ 4.8 on my machine.

I wrote a simply hello.c and compiled with command,
g++ hello.c -o hello

And it gave me the error that,
as: unrecognized option '--32'.

And I am surprised I did not find any result on Google in regard to this error. Need some help! Thank you.

Comment: Is your code C or C++? a .c file extension implies C, but g++ is used for C++ compilation?

Comment: I tried gcc for .c and g++ for cpp, but none works. But then I reinstalled the OS, then it worked, seems, me old install got messed up.

Comment: From the edit: "Solution: I reinstalled the OS then it worked. Seems the conf got messed up." Do not put "SOLVED" in the title or put the solution in the question. The solution goes as an answer.